# Showing drop pin after relaunch app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, annotations, save

I have application with map where you can make an annotation by dropping a pin. How can I save the annotation, so you can see it when the application is closed and re-opened?

My code's for annotation

```
    func addAnnotation(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {

        var touch = gesture.locationInView(self.Mapa)
        var coordinate = Mapa.convertPoint(touch, toCoordinateFromView: self.Mapa)

        var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

        var loc = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                let placemark = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark)

                self.cislo = placemark.subThoroughfare != nil ? placemark.subThoroughfare : ""
                self.adresa = placemark.thoroughfare != nil ? placemark.thoroughfare : ""
                self.mesto = placemark.subAdministrativeArea != nil ? placemark.subAdministrativeArea : ""
                self.krajina = placemark.administrativeArea != nil ? placemark.administrativeArea : ""
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = placemark.location.coordinate
                annotation.title = self.adresa! + " " + self.cislo!
                self.Mapa.addAnnotation(annotation)
                println("Špendlík pridaný!")


            }

        })

    }

}
```

In case you want to see whole code 
http://pastebin.com/d89kTrL7

Comment: going from background mode and coming back or returning after terminating application ?

Comment: returning after terminating application

Comment: you can use NSUserDefaults  to save the longitude and latitude and later retreive it form NSUserDefauls and then show the pin annotation again using the information from userdefaults

Comment: Can you write me example of code? Because I never use it.

Comment: should i write an overview of what should you do ?then i might help now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would save the data into userdefaults as

```
 func addAnnotation(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
       if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        var touch = gesture.locationInView(self.Mapa)
        var coordinate = Mapa.convertPoint(touch, toCoordinateFromView: self.Mapa)

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setDouble(coordinate.longitude, forKey: "longitudeNameKey")
        defaults.setDouble(coordinate.latitude, forKey: "latitudeNameKey")
        defaults.synchronize()

        var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
        var loc = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                let placemark = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark)

                self.cislo = placemark.subThoroughfare != nil ? placemark.subThoroughfare : ""
                self.adresa = placemark.thoroughfare != nil ? placemark.thoroughfare : ""
                self.mesto = placemark.subAdministrativeArea != nil ? placemark.subAdministrativeArea : ""
                self.krajina = placemark.administrativeArea != nil ? placemark.administrativeArea : ""
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = placemark.location.coordinate
                annotation.title = self.adresa! + " " + self.cislo!
                self.Mapa.addAnnotation(annotation)
                println("Špendlík pridaný!")


            }

        })

    }

}
```

You can save info to NSUserDefaults when the annotations are created.And somewhere in viewDidLoad method you just get all the info from user defaults and then display the annotations.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      loadAnnotationFromUserDefaults()

    }
```

use `loadAnnotationFromUserDefaults` method to deserializes the list of coordinates previously saved to `NSUserDefaults`. Through this method you also load the coordinates as annotations on the map view.

```
 func  loadAnnotationFromUserDefaults(){
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let  long= defaults.doubleForKey("longitudeNameKey")
        let lat = defaults.doubleForKey("latitudeNameKey")
        println("\(long)")
        println("\(lat)")
         //You got the coordinates that you lost after terminating now load the coordinates as annotation to mapview
    }
```

You should set new coordinates and terminate application ..notice the coordinates..now again reopen your application ..now you get again those see on the log

P.S code not tested and should change according to your application architecture...only take it as a reference.

Here is the demo project i set up for you
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6dTvD1JbkgBRnN2QllWWlJqd0E&authuser=0

Comment: yeah..theres where you have to put your mind on..Each time it adds to a new instance of the array..You have to append the new annotation in the same array..May be getting the array from the user defaults and appending there...please try to do it on your own?